# How can I fix the missing duration of a video file from a RTSP stream on Gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, mkv

I'm using the following pipeline to listen to a RTSP stream and save a video file:

`gst-launch-1.0 -q rtspsrc location=rtsp://<ip>:<port>/video ! decodebin ! autovideoconvert ! x264enc pass=5 quantizer=25 speed-preset=6 ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=<filename>`

But even though I can see the files generated, they lack the duration of the video when playing on VLC.

I can fix it by passing it through ffmpeg later, but I want to generate the video from gstreamer already completely valid. How can I fix this pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

`gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location=rtsp://<ip>:<port>/video ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location="filename.mp4"`

This will create a video with duration shown correctly